# How to convert a date column to MMDDYYYY format to compare other tables columns with MMDDYYYY format

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select  to_date(to_number(to_char(created_on_date,'MMDDYYYY')),'MMDDYYYY') from is_mdm_customer
```

above query is giving

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select  to_date(to_number(to_char(created_on_date,'MMDDYYYY')),'MMDDYYYY') from is_mdm_customer
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: What datatypes are these `Dates` of yours?  You're not keeping them as VARCHARs are you!?

Comment: What oh what are you trying to do with that nesting of `to_xxx` functions?

Answer (score 2):

You should store Date types as DATE columns, not varchars.  If you need month, day and year you can add columns for those, too.

Just compare the Dates.  If you don't want to compare hours, minutes, seconds I'd store them that way: set the times to midnight on the day when you INSERT or UPDATE it.  Then you can compare DATEs directly.

Formats should only affect view rendering, nothing more.

Comment: They must be DATE, or that wouldn't make sense to do a TO_CHAR first, no ? I suppose he wants to work with the dates without minutes seconds etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to trim off the time portion use TRUNCATE().

```
select  TRUNC(created_on_date) from is_mdm_customer
```

You can also pass a parameter to the TRUNCATE function to truncate the date differently. However EXTRACT() can often be better if you just want the YEAR.

Ref: [Oracle 11g Trunc(Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if the column **created_on_date** is defined as the Date column.

select to_char(created_on_date,'MMDDYYYY') from is_mdm_customer;